# Google Cloud Function for creating windows vm password automatically

Tags: java, python, go, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I try to create a Google Cloud Function that automates the process of creating a windows password for my vm instance. I found this link: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/windows/automate-pw-generation#python

Unfortunately I use Javascript regularly wherefore I need help with Java, Python or Go. In this case I decided to use python but it doesn't matter.

My settings are:
Runtime: Python 3.7
Entry point: main

**Code**

```
import base64
import copy
import datetime
import json
import time

from Crypto.Cipher import PKCS1_OAEP
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from Crypto.Util.number import long_to_bytes

from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

def GetCompute():
    credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
    compute = build('compute', 'v1', credentials=credentials)
    return compute

def GetInstance(compute, instance, zone, project):
    cmd = compute.instances().get(instance=instance, project=project, zone=zone)
    return cmd.execute()

def GetKey():
    key = RSA.generate(2048)
    return key


def GetModulusExponentInBase64(key):
    mod = long_to_bytes(key.n)
    exp = long_to_bytes(key.e)

    modulus = base64.b64encode(mod)
    exponent = base64.b64encode(exp)

    return modulus, exponent


def GetExpirationTimeString():
    utc_now = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
    expire_time = utc_now + datetime.timedelta(minutes=5)
    return expire_time.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')


def GetJsonString(user, modulus, exponent, email):
    expire = GetExpirationTimeString()
    data = {'userName': user,
            'modulus': modulus,
            'exponent': exponent,
            'email': email,
            'expireOn': expire}
    return json.dumps(data)


def UpdateWindowsKeys(old_metadata, metadata_entry):
    new_metadata = copy.deepcopy(old_metadata)
    new_metadata['items'] = [{
        'key': "windows-keys",
        'value': metadata_entry
    }]
    return new_metadata


def UpdateInstanceMetadata(compute, instance, zone, project, new_metadata):
    cmd = compute.instances().setMetadata(instance=instance, project=project, zone=zone, body=new_metadata)
    return cmd.execute()


def GetSerialPortFourOutput(compute, instance, zone, project):
    port = 4
    cmd = compute.instances().getSerialPortOutput(instance=instance, project=project, zone=zone, port=port)
    output = cmd.execute()
    return output['contents']


def GetEncryptedPasswordFromSerialPort(serial_port_output, modulus):
    output = serial_port_output.split('\n')
    for line in reversed(output):
        try:
            entry = json.loads(line)
            if modulus == entry['modulus']:
                return entry['encryptedPassword']
        except ValueError:
            pass


def DecryptPassword(encrypted_password, key):
    decoded_password = base64.b64decode(encrypted_password)
    cipher = PKCS1_OAEP.new(key)
    password = cipher.decrypt(decoded_password)
    return password


def main(request):
    instance = 'my-instance'
    zone = 'my-zone'
    project = 'my-project'
    user = 'my-user'
    email = 'my-email'

    compute = GetCompute()
    key = GetKey()
    modulus, exponent = GetModulusExponentInBase64(key)

    instance_ref = GetInstance(compute, instance, zone, project)
    old_metadata = instance_ref['metadata']

    metadata_entry = GetJsonString(user, modulus, exponent, email)
    new_metadata = UpdateWindowsKeys(old_metadata, metadata_entry)
    result = UpdateInstanceMetadata(compute, instance, zone, project, new_metadata)

    time.sleep(30)

    serial_port_output = GetSerialPortFourOutput(compute, instance, zone, project)
    enc_password = GetEncryptedPasswordFromSerialPort(serial_port_output, modulus)
    password = DecryptPassword(enc_password, key)

    print(f'Username:    {user}')
    print(f'Password:    {password}')
    ip = instance_ref['networkInterfaces'][0]['accessConfigs'][0]['natIP']
    print(f'IP Address:    {ip}')
```

As you can see I added my details to the main function and my requirements.txt looks like this:

```
pycrypto==2.6.1
oauth2client==4.1.3
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work and I receive the following error:

> Object of type bytes is not JSON serializable.

I hope you can help me here. Thanks.

========

EDIT

I added ".decode()" to modulus and exponent to avoid the previous error:

```
def GetJsonString(user, modulus, exponent, email):
    expire = GetExpirationTimeString()
    data = {'userName': user,
            'modulus': modulus.decode(),
            'exponent': exponent.decode(),
            'email': email,
            'expireOn': expire}
    return json.dumps(data)
```

But I am still not able to generate a password. I receive an error at "serial_port_output = GetSerialPortFourOutput(compute, instance, zone, project)":

> error decoding modulus: illegal base64 data at input byte 1

Answer (score 1):

Your function is not working because you're using Python 2.x print statement instead of python3 print() function.

Replace

```
print 'Username:   {0}'.format(user)
```

with

```
print ('Username:   {0}'.format(user))
```

You can also use python 3.6+ f-strings instead of format()

```
pring(f'Username:    {user}')
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. That's right. Thank you. Unfortunately another error appears: "Object of type bytes is not JSON serializable". The problem has to be in this line: "metadata_entry = GetJsonString(user, modulus, exponent, email)". I tried the code line by line and in this line the error occurs.

Comment: @MarvinHauser Are you sure modulus and exponent are strings? base64.encode returns bytes from a byte-like object. You'll need to return modulus.encode('utf80),exponent('utf8') in getModulusExponentInBase64 - tell me if that's the problem and I'll update the anwer.